# Google Cloud Messaging more than 1000 notification

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

i have a system with a `push notification` using `gcm` however when i try to send more than 1000 notification he give me a error "Number of messages on bulk (1461) exceeds maximum allowed (1000)". there is a way to resolve this situation?for example send 50 000 notification at same time.
thanks for the answers
Google Cloud Messaging more than 1000 notification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> there is a way to resolve this situation?for example send 50 000 notification at same time

No. You are welcome to divide your list into 1,000-recipient subsets, and send a GCM message to each subset.

Comment: i did this option, i divide my list into 1000, however it takes me 4 minutes to deliver all the notifications, is there a way to deliver faster? sorry for the english

Comment: @user3250732: You will need to do your own performance analysis of your own server implementation to determine where your problem lies.